# SQL Server Unique Constraints Without Sort Order

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, unique-constraint

In an SQL Server database, I created a Unique Constraint to ensure that one of it's tables contains only unique pairs of values.

The problem now is that the order of records I get is different. The records are sorted, but I want them to come in original order, just as they exist in the table, without any sorting.

I've checked everywhere, but couldn't find a way to create a unique constraint without sort order. Is this supported at all?

Comment: What is `default order`?

Comment: Application logic should not depend on the arbitrary default order of records stored in the database.

Comment: L.B., I mean the original order records stored in the database.

Comment: mellamokb, if I add an index column for the order, how can I force the DB to use it for sorting, while keeping a pair of two other columns unique?

Comment: DB can always change the order of records depending on internal algorithms and how it stores the records. See @mellamokb 's comment

Comment: Does the table have a primary key, did you create a unique constraint or a clustered index?

Comment: The table has a primary key, int ID.

Comment: @Gratzy why does that matter? Even if there is a clustered index, rows are not guaranteed to come back in any order (even though that's what you will typically observe).

Comment: @LoveDotNet: You can create a unique index on the two columns that are supposed to be unique.  The unique index only applies to the fields in the index, regardless of other fields (i.e., it doesn't matter if there exists some field that has a different value for every row, the unique index will still apply).  If you need a field for sorting, you can add `ORDER BY [MySortingField]` to queries that you retrieve from the database.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand just trying to learn more about the structure of his table he may have a primary key already defined he can order by to accomplish what he wants

Comment: @Gratzy not to nitpick but that would be an identity column or a monotonically increasing column (such as a datetime column with a default of getdate()), neither of which obviously need to be a primary key (though many people think an identity column always has to be the primary key). And it would still require an outer order by.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand you are being nitpicky, I'm simply trying to find out more information so a complete answer can be given by me or someone else, that's what comments are for

Comment: @Gratzy I just want to make sure that your question doesn't imply to other readers that a primary key could be relied on for "default ordering" instead of the unique constraint the OP was trying to create. Relax, it isn't all about you.

Comment: @Gratzy I am just making sure that common myths and misconceptions aren't perpetuated by potentially misleading comments, that's all. I'm plenty relaxed, I just see a lot of opportunity for misleading information and want to make a point of clarifying it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The records are sorted, but I want them to come in original order, just as they exist in the table, without any 
>   sorting.

Ah, the old sort issue - SQL  for beginners.

TABLES have a sort order that is the order of the clustered index. Missing that the odder is undefined.

RESULTS have *NO ORDER UNLESS DEFINED*. SQL can change the order if it thinks it can process a query better. This is FUNDAMENTAL - you deal with data sets, and data sets per se are not ordered.

So, if you want an order, ASK FOR IT.

> but couldn't find a way to create a unique constraint without sort order.

Why would you need an order for a unique constraint? A unique index should suffice, or? I would NOT make uniqueness a constraint but put - standard - a unique index on the fields. Especially as the index is good for - validating that they are unique and thus needed anyway.

Comment: +1 - If you want a specific order, the *ONLY* way to guarantee it is to add an ORDER BY to the outer query. Even if there is a clustered index - this dictates how SQL should try and store the data, not how it needs to return it. As an aside, there really is no difference between a unique constraint and a unique index - they are both implemented the exact same way. Which you use should depend on semantics (e.g. is the index to enforce uniqueness or as a side effect of trying to improve performance).

Comment: +1 I was writing my answer while you posted yours. I think its a bit sad microsoft dont emphasize the no-default-order issue on their select documentation page in the msdn. Probably thousands of programmers have assumed the identity sets the order, and they all might still see their selects fail due to that.

Comment: OK, then why Visual Studio database designer forces to choose a Sort Order (Ascending/Descending) when creating an index?

Comment: @LoveDotNet That is how the index stores the data in the index, and relates to how seeks/scans occur against the index, not how SQL Server returns the data when it is retrieved via a query.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, I think I understand it now. Change of the arbitrary order after creating an index made me think that the sort order you specify in an index affects order of the records the server returns. I will now use an explicit orderby in the query.

Comment: Great ;) This is an error many have run in - but it is also one that is at the core of SQL ;)

Comment: In my case, the order was originally defined by the pk, this was the "default order" - the order in which rows were added. Now, after adding the unique constraint (which demands a sort order if using the MSSQL Management UI) the order is dictated by that unique constraint instead of the pk. How can I change the precedence?

Answer (score 3):

IF you want to get your records in the "original" order - you should use any field which will mark this order, such as an identity sequence / primary key (probably the best option you can use), or a creation date or anything else.

The rows in ur table (physically, in the file) are actually sorted by a particular order only when you use a [clustered index](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1254/clustered-tables-vs-heap-tables/), however, even in that case, there are no guarantees whatsover that this or any order will be preserved when you selected rows from that table, without any order by clause.

Usually, with a clustered table, You'll get the results in the order of the clustered index, however this is not something you can rely on, and wherever order is important, you should provide ORDER BY in your query.

Answer (score -2):

Using ROW_NUMBER you can get how your order is stored without using sort_order. I hope it help.

Comment: That isn't what `ROW_NUMBER` does.